# composer require s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver failed in laravel 8.54

Tags: php, laravel, composer-php, sendgrid

I downloaded the latest laravel framwork 8.54 and tried to install  `composer require s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver`, but it failed.
[image]

is there any solution?

Comment: Please share more details, like the error message in text form and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: this detail is clear enough. that is simple error.

Comment: If that is a simple error, what keeps you from fixing it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like version 4 of `s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver` requires version 9 of `illuminate/mail`, but Laravel 8.x uses version 8.x of `illuminate/mail`.

Can you try to install version 3 of `s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver` instead?

```
composer require s-ichikawa/laravel-sendgrid-driver:3.0.4
```